# Custom errors with Is and As not working as expected

Tags: go

I'm having a lot of problems with the errors interface and custom errors.  Specifically Is and As seems to be very unreliable.  Documentation on this isn't well described with few examples for custom types like this.  Can someone please explain why this isn't working?

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

var FatalError *fatalError

type fatalError struct {
    msg string
}

func (e *fatalError) Error() string {
    return e.msg
}

func NewFatalError(msg string, vars ...interface{}) error {
    return &fatalError{
        msg: fmt.Sprintf(msg, vars...),
    }
}

func main() {
    err := NewFatalError("test")
    if errors.Is(err, FatalError) {
        fmt.Println("FatalError Is FatalError type")
    }

    if errors.As(err, &FatalError) {
        fmt.Println("FatalError As be FatalError type")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
FatalError As be FatalError type
```

I would have expected both lines to be outputted, indicating both Is and As are returning true.   What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The variable `FatalError` is `nil`, and `NewFatalError` doesn't assign any value to it but creates a new `fatalError`. But even with the same content (which isn't the case here), they aren't equal b/c they are pointers referencing to different memory addresses.

Comment: strange because I've seen other examples and even had one that appeared to work correctly without necessarily assigning a value to FatalError.

Once I tried to create this type like this it doesn't work.   And to me it doesn't explain why As works but Is doesn't

Comment: A quick look at Is seems to check for equality using type (reflection) rather than memory address

Comment: `As` checks for the type. Even an uninitialized (i.e. `nil`) `fatalError` variable has the same type as a new one, which is, well, `fatalError` basically. ;) But it's _not_ equal, let alone the same instance as `FatalError`. For that, you've got to initialize the `FatalError` variable and return it all the times. Adding a `message` won't work then ofc. Edit: can't check it out atm, but even if it checks via reflection, the comparison to `nil` will fail if your `err` isn't `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, in that case I just need to change use As rather than Is.  

The documentation sure could be clearer.

Comment: Just looking at the documentation myself atm, I agree on that!

Comment: "strange because I've seen other examples" - `errors.Is` will work for errors like `context.Cancelled` because [a single sentinel value is created](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.3:src/context/context.go;l=157;bpv=1;bpt=1). [This blog post](https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors) might help (it's old but I don't think anything has changed).